# Drupal View, get node id to use a template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

How can I get node id for the `Drupal View` I just created?

The view has a `Page path`, and I can see the `View`.

However, in order to exclude the sidebars from it I had to create a Basic Page and then a template `page--node--nodeid.tpl.php` to override it. Then, in there, I rendered the view.

But since the View already is a page (I guess) and all content is a node, it should have a node id. That way I wouldn't need to create a `Basic Page`.

I've tried looking at `Theme Information` but those templates overrides are for the view, not for the entire page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not *all* content is a node. Your Page View is likely displaying fields from certain other nodes, however.

If your goal is to hide those sidebars on that particular page, you could go into `page.tpl.php` and do something like:

```
<?php 
$path = drupal_get_path_alias(current_path());

if($path != "/my/view/path"){
  print render($content['my_sidebar_region']);
}
```